# Best node js package for file transfer between client and server?

Tags: node.js, ftp, node-modules

There are many packages for file transfer between client and server in node JS.
But is there any particular package which transfer any files between client to server and vice versa in an easy manner.

Comment: What is the client?

Comment: Just a web app.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP?

It's great for this sort of thing, and works in browsers as well.